# Drop works with href of #, but not 'home/index'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5.2

My dropdown menu works when I have # as the href value, but not when I have a link.

Bootstrap 4.3.1

I get a query selector error:

> SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern.
>       Selected Element

…

```
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">

              <a href="home/index" class="nav-link text-color-white dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"> 
                        Home
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                 <li><a href="#" class="">Section 1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#" class=""> Section 2</a></li>                    
                 <li><a href="#" class=""> Section 3</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in Bootstrap that they are in the process of fixing for their next release. [Source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/issues/170#issuecomment-454044407)

[A solution (many solutions exist in this thread)](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/27903#issuecomment-452610300)

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown" id="parentDropdown">
   <a href="home/index"
      class="nav-link text-color-white dropdown-toggle" 
      data-toggle="dropdown" 
      data-target="#parentDropdown"
      role="button" 
      aria-expanded="false"> 
        Home
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="">Section 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class=""> Section 2</a></li>                    
      <li><a href="#" class=""> Section 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

The dropdown needs an ID and the link needs a `data-target` pointing to that ID

Comment: I read the thread ,and tried your solution, the menu opens now, but the link does not work.

Comment: Any ideas? I used the above code and still not working, it does not error like it did, but if I click the parent, nav, the menu item, it does not go anywhere